Wegas-react code build successfully on windows intellij but giving error on ubuntu
I am trying to build the code https://github.com/Heigvd/Wegas/tree/master/wegas-app/src/main/node/wegas-react using yarn build. It builds successfully on my windows intellij but I am unable to run it on ubuntu. Following error occurred.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (yarn run build) on project wegas-app: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (yarn run build) on project wegas-app: Command execution failed. at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196) at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:569) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed. at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:478) at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196) at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:569) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348) Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404) at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166) at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982) at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929) at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457) at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196) at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:569) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
please assists
I am trying to build the above code and want it to be executed successfully
